Issue with Python Path After Removing Anaconda
I'm facing an issue with the installation of Python on my computer. Even after deleting all files related to Anaconda and completely uninstalling Anaconda 3, the path to Python still points to Anaconda 3.What I have already tried:
Deleted all files and folders related to Anaconda.
Checked environment variables and ensured there are no references to Anaconda.
Reinstalled Python.Despite these steps, the problem persists. Are there any additional steps I can take to completely remove traces of Anaconda and properly set up Python?
Expected the Python path to update to the new installation directory, free from any references to Anaconda.

what operating system are you referring to ? Have you tried manually adding your new python kernel to PYTHONPATH ? (pls indicate if you don't know what I mean by 2nd question - it's pretty crucial here)

If you are window 10 and up, you could try to edit your path variables by

Going to the search bar in the bottom left corner of the screen and typing Edit the system environment Variables

Click on the option that matches what you have typed.

Click the environment variables button.

Look in the user variables for {YOURUSERNAME} table. Find and click on Path.

Click the edit for the user variables table.

Delete the broken reference

Press ok and the broken reference should be gone!


